# Get-Item Powershell: Treating foreign characters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've got a large powershell program that needs to check details on many files in a server. The program uses `Get-ChildItem` as well as `Get-Item`. It seems decently robust when it comes to dealing with strange names as I have used `-literalpath`, and it works for 99.9% of files, including ones with japanese names (because it is a japanese server) or with wildcard characters (`[]`) in them.

What my current problem is comes from this line:

```
$file = (Get-Item -literalpath $file_path -force)
```

and returns the following error:
(I have censored some of the path into "----" for security, ignore this)

```
 Get-Item : Cannot find path 'E:\----\---\-------\-----\23 RNPO Meeting Data ' because it does not exist.
At H:\----\------\----------.ps1:630 char:19
+     $file = (Get-Item <<<<  -literalpath $file_path -force)###
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:\----\---\---...O Meeting Data :String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

After looking into it, it looks like the character is a japanese space character. Specifically the last character of the string is "[IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm)" 0x3000 (12288<sub>10</sub>)

When read or outputted in most places, it is treated like a normal space character, which is the root of the problem. When the Get-Item tries to find the folder, it reads for a name that ends with a normal space character, rather than a japanese one. (Despite `-literalpath`)

Can anyone suggest a way to use `Get-Item` despite this weird character?

**EDIT:** I am trying to use `$file_name -like "*$([char]12288)*"` to detect this character in file/folder names. For now it will just throw an preventative error, can anyone recommend a more complete solution?

**WEIRDER EDIT:** Apparently, there are many more files that contain this character that are treated without any problems. This makes things a lot more complicated..

Comment: Is it true that your file's name ends with a space and does not have an extension?

Comment: @Vesper I realised afterwards that the file is in fact a folder. My bad. It does end with a strange character though. Space character: " "; this character: "　"

Comment: @MartinSmith Copypaste said 227,128,128 in UTF8. Google says "IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE" 0x3000 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm Nice char btw.

Comment: Hi. If you do like this ---> Get-Item -literalpath $file_path -force | select @{n="name";e={$_.Name.ToString().Split(" ")}} error appears? or like this Get-Item -literalpath $file_path -force | select @{n="name";e={$_.Name.ToString().Split(" ")[0]}} error appears?

Comment: @Vitaly sadly, neither of those works.